# Php array to ajax var

Tags: php, ajax

I have an opensliding side panel in wich I display content. I have a working example, but it works on an ajax var that I've put in. I would like to scan a folder for the files loaded in my ajax code. How can I pass folder content into my ajax?

**PHP**

```
    <div class="standorte-wrapper">
      <div class="panel left"><!-- start pannel left -->
         <div class="pan-item tl">
           <button  class="show-hide" data-ajaxFile="0">OPEN</button>
         </div> 
         <div class="pan-item tr">
           <button  class="show-hide" data-ajaxFile="1">OPEN</button>
         </div>
         <div class="pan-item bl">
           <button  class="show-hide" data-ajaxFile="2">OPEN</button>
         </div>
         <div class="pan-item br">
           <button  class="show-hide" data-ajaxFile="3">OPEN</button>
         </div>
      </div><!-- end pannel left -->
      <div id="open" class="panel right"><!-- start sliding pannel right -->
         <div class="close-button">
           <a href="#" id="close" class="close">close</a>
         </div>
         <div id="content">
           <div id="php-content"></div>
         </div>
       </div>
   </div>
```

**AJAX**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

      var ajaxUrls = [
        '/standorteContent/brauerstrasse.php',
        '/standorteContent/gutterstrasse.php',
        '/standorteContent/kauffmannweg.php',
        '/standorteContent/konradstrasse.php'
      ];

      var ajaxFiles = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < ajaxUrls.length; i++) {
       $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          url: ajaxUrls[i],
          success: function(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          ajaxFiles.push(data);
       }
      });
    }
    $('.adres-wrap > button').on('click', function() {
      if ($('.panel.left').hasClass('open')) {
        //alert('already open');
       } else {
       $('.panel.left').addClass('open', 1000, "easeInBack");
       $('.standorte-wrapper').addClass('expand');
       }

     $('#php-content').html(ajaxFiles[$(this).attr('data-ajaxFile')]);
     setTimeout(function (){
       $('.panel.right div').fadeIn(400);
     }, 500);   
    });

    $('#close').on('click', function() {
        $('.panel.right div').fadeOut(400);
        setTimeout(function (){
           $('.panel.left').removeClass('open');
           $('.standorte-wrapper').removeClass('expand');
        }, 500);
     });
    });
```

**LOOKS LIKE**
[image]

**QUESTION**

How can I change so that I don't have to add `data-ajaxFile="nr"` manual for every button? And I would like `ajaxUrls` get the path for php files only in a directory on my server. Can anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: What I don't understand is the reason why you make 4 extra server requests upon the request to load the page. This makes 5 in total, while PHP is perfectly capable to print the result of those files directly in `<div id="php-content"<?= 'this div' ?></div>`.

Comment: I cant't follow? I make one request no? To load data onclick into `<div id="#content"></div>` so onclick it loads data from article number in content. Wich works fine.

Comment: It works fine, 1 server request to load the page, 4 additional server requests to load the contents. But that's hardly efficient. Instead print the contents to a hidden div and toggle it on a click event.

Comment: Ok, but that does not answer my original question. How can i link my button on files in a folder automaticly

Comment: "How can I pass folder content into my ajax?". You mean you want to pass a folder name to the server and it will return a list of all the files in that folder? Your wording is not very clear

Comment: I want a list of urls to files in a folder, that folder is on my server. Like 'var ajaxUrls' is right now. But I want ik to be automatic. Also I don't want to have to add the 'data-ajaxFile' to link the urls to the urls. basicly, I want mu buttons to load the right .php file from a folder. Without manualy adjusting a var